# Почему SVG background неправильно отображается в firefox?

Tags: svg

Почему в chrome текст отображается правильно, а в firefox не отображается background на тексте?
Подскажите кто знаком с svg ?
[Пример ошибки](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNLpBr)

```html
<svg>
<defs>
<filter id="blur" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"></feGaussianBlur>
</filter>
<filter id="blur2" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0 50" in="SourceGraphic">
</feGaussianBlur></filter>
<pattern id="svg_text" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="1304" height="705" x="0" y="0">
    <image xlink:href="http://www.saitadmin.ru/faili_na_razdacu/bg_logo_1.jpg" width="1304" height="705"></image>
</pattern>
</defs>
<g>
<text class="fill tx1" dy="0.3em" y="50%" x="50%" style="fill:url(#svg_text) none; filter: url(#blur2);">wood</text>
<text class="tx2" dy="0.3em" y="50%" x="50%" style="filter:url(#blur);">wood</text>
<text class="fill" dy="0.3em" y="50%" x="50%" style="fill:url(#svg_text) none;">wood</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Что здесь может быть неправильно ?

Comment: У меня одинаково отображается в ФФ и Хроме. Какие версии браузеров используете?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно указать явный background-size. Читаем:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: Попробовал к image style="background-size: 100% 100%;" добавить, не работает, можно Вас попросить пример кинуть ?